# What's the version number for the next production version of Groovy from Codehaus?

Tags: groovy

Does anyone know the version number for the next production release of Groovy from Codehaus?

`groovy-2.4-rc-2` was released a week ago, but I'm not sure whether the production release will have the same version number. The production release of Groovy 1.5 was changed from 1.1 after the final release candidate but before the production release as shown

```
groovy-binary-1.1-rc-3.zip    28-Nov-2007 06:41   7.3M
groovy-binary-1.5.0.zip       07-Dec-2007 14:18   7.4M
```

so I don't want to commit to any naming and numbering plans until after the upcoming production release, unless there's someone out there who can give a definitive answer!

Comment: Still waiting on an answer from someone in the know, preferably with a link to a Groovy project page or mailing list post, not someone's private blog or statement in an online newspaper. This would help with configuring Java and Groovy version number meta info into many various different disconnected infrastructures (e.g. Linux, Windows, etc).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Download page is http://groovy.codehaus.org/Download, latest release for production use there 2.3.9. Next production releases are 2.4.0 and 2.3.10

Comment: Looks like someone resisted the urge to rename it Groovy 3.0 at the last moment.

Comment: we actually considered doing this just for you ;)